# When creating an Azure Static Web App with Azure Devops no Organization is visible

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-static-web-app

My Azure Devops organization is linked to my Azure Subscription but in Azure Portal, when I try to create a Static Web App using an Azure DevOps source repository, the dropdowns are empty.

I imagine this has something to do with permissions or subscription setup I tried creating a brand new DevOps organization, did not seem to help.

This integration is a fairly new feature and I can't find documentation on specific requirements that would enable this.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This actually requires that the user currently logged in at the portal has access rights to the organization under a certain domain (it has nothing to do with the rights management on the portal side).

Please go to this link to check:

https://aex.dev.azure.com/me

Please first get the domain of the organization you want(use the user you used in the portal):

[image]

Then make sure your user's domain in the Azure Active Directory where the portal is located is the same as the DevOps domain:

[image]

For example, on my side, my user in AAD 'A' has access to many organizations, but in AAD 'B' my user has no access to any organizations. So if my user is in AAD 'B' in the portal, no organization will be listed.

[image]